# Login and Register in woocommerce site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use Wordpress 5.2 with Woocommerce 3.6.2. I need when the visitor reaches the site, in the menu bar the visitant see the options "Login" and "Register". Once the user registers or login on the site, the options "Login" and "Register" disappear and the site show the options of "My Account" as a drop-down menu next to the options "Cart", "End Purchase", "Logout"

How can I achieve this? I'm looking for information but I do not give yet with a solution.

Comment: How are things? Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm sorry to respond so late, the example does not work for me and I still have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to extend your (child-) themes functions.php with the following:

```
function so_loginout_menu_links( $items, $args ) {
   if ( $args->theme_location == 'primary' && function_exists('is_woocommerce') ) {
      if (is_user_logged_in()) {
         $items .= '<li><a href="'. wp_logout_url() .'">'. __("Log Out") .'</a></li>';
         $items .= '<li><a href="'. get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ).'">'. __("My Account") .'</a></li>';
      } else {
         $items .= '<li><a href="'. wp_registration_url() .'">'. __("Log In") .'</a></li>';
         $items .= '<li><a href="'. site_url('/wp-login.php?action=register').'">'. __("Register") .'</a></li>';
      }
   }
   return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'so_loginout_menu_links', 10, 2 );
```

This extends the menu "primary" with two links by filtering it, dependant on whether the user is logged in or not. I've added a check for woocommerce as well, as the account page is woocommerce specific and might throw errors in case it's deactivated.

"primary" in the code above might need to be replaced with "primary-menu", "top" or whatever your themes primary navigation menu is called.

Also make sure that Administration > Settings > General > Membership "Anyone can register" is checked, otherwise the link may not be shown.

Note there's no additional CSS in my example now, so the additional items will not yet be in a dropdown or anything. To get that, inspect your existing menu items and add the according classes and additional  top level items into the code above accordingly.

Comment: Im sorry I did not answer before, **thanks for the help** but it did not work for me.